# Нечитаемый или не читаемый?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Слово *нечитаемый* может иметь два значения: (1) трудно прочесть, (2) никто не читает. В первом значении это явное прилагательное, а вот во втором значении больше напоминает причастие.

У Розенталя для слов на *-мый* есть особое правило: [§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)

Слова на -мый, образованные от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида, могут быть как страдательными причастиями настоящего времени (частица не пишется раздельно), так и прилагательными (частица не пишется слитно).
Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия: *не любимый матерью ребёнок*;  При наличии других пояснительных слов мы имеем дело с прилагательными на *-мый*: нелюбимые в детстве игры.

А вот относится ли это правило к слову *нечитаемый*?

Итак, — *нечитаемый почерк* / *никем не читаемый автор* ―  здесь все понятно. А при наличии зависимых слов (не в Т.п.)  форма очень похожа на причастие, так стоит ли ее писать слитно?

Примеры с раздельным написанием.

1) Но был некий **не читаемый** поверхностно смысл в выборе.

2) Навстречу уже поднимались: писатель, давно **не читаемый**...

3) Настанет время, когда он, **не читаемый** и поругаемый, будет  широко признан (при обособлении!)

4) Анатолий Каменский (ныне, кажется, уж **не читаемый**).

Answer (score 1):

Обращу внимание, что у этих слов разное значение.

У прилагательного "нечитаемый" только одно словарное значение: "тот, который сложно или невозможно прочитать". Причастие "читаемый" с частицей "не-" имеет, как правило, иной смысл: "тот, который/которого никто не читает".

Поэтому "не читаемый автор" - это всегда причастие, всегда раздельно (Примеры 2-4).

Answer (score 0):

1. "Смысл" не является "читаемым поверхностно", поэтому раздельно. Отрицание применяется к словосочетанию.
2. Зависимое слово характеризует прилагательное, взятое с отрицанием. Нечитаемый в течение какого периода? - Нечитаемый давно.
3. Зависимых слов или других поводов писать раздельно не наблюдается, поэтому прилагательное пишется слитно.
4. То же, что и во втором случае. "Ныне" относится к прилагательному, взятому с отрицанием, дополнительных "отягчающих обстоятельств" нет, поэтому слитно. С другой стороны, "ныне не читаемый, но всё ещё любимый". В общем, по умолчанию пишем слитно.

P.S. Нет, ссылок не планируется :)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь также важно значение слов. Прямое значение - «не читаемый», пишем раздельно. Переносное значение - «нечитаемый взгляд», пишем слитно.